# Can anyone resolve this issues? Two buttons (add to cart )are coming with the disabled mode

Tags: module, custom, addtocart

[image: Two buttons are coming]I need to apply the code for the add to cart button but it is coming in disabled mode hence unable to do the required changes.**strong text**

Comment: It just happened suddenly? Have you installed any extension?

Comment: before that I was working on a module for changing the fucntionality of it but that was seperate

Comment: It happened suddenly right? Then you should revert your changes

Comment: that cant be possible cause I worked on different modules

Comment: Don't know which one to change.

Comment: could you help me with the smtp configuration for the magento 2

Comment: for SMTP configuration install mageplaza extension https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp

Comment: the page inwhich all products of one category are shown, what it is called?